# How to make OpenGL program run on Graphics Card by C++ MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, graphics, mfc

I have coded a OpenGL program with c++ MFC, but the render speed is unbearablely slow.. I finally founded that the problem is because the program running using the ***Integrated Graphics***, and it runs very smooth and perfect after I forced to set the program running using Graphics Card in NVIDIA panel....

Can I change the default graphics the program using to Graphics Card in code level or VC project level? And how to do it?

Development Environment: 64bit Win7, Visual Studio 2010, C++, MFC, OpenGL
Hardware: i7-2670QM, NVIDA GeForce GT 540M with 2G dedicate memory

Comment: Sounds like an OS or bios setting, not something you would have much control over in code.

Comment: Sometimes OS tries to be smart and sets integrated or discrete card for given app. Configuration can be possibly changed in the driver panel - set your app (created in VC) to be run with NVIDIA

Comment: @fen, If a real software is about to hand to users, it is impossible to ask users themselves to change settings their own, what can I do about this? Can I add some code to force the OS runs my program under graphic card?

Comment: to be honest I do not know... my friend got similar problem, but after some fights with the OS he simply changed the OS...